# Adicionar elementos a uma lista

Tags: php

Boa noite, eu tenho uma ideia porem não sei como executa-la. Eu estou fazendo um **sistema de pedidos**, onde será selecionado um cliente e os respectivos **pedidos**, e a maneira mais correta que pensei em fazer isso foi fazer com que o usuário adicione os pedidos em uma lista, mas ai que vem o problema, eu não consigo pensar em um jeito de a lista ir se completando **sem que a pagina seja recarregada**. Resumindo, quando o usuário clicar em **"OK"**, um novo pedido seria adicionado na tabela na mesma pagina, sem que a mesma seja recarregada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso você deve fazer com **ajax** e **jquery** amigo. Quando a pessoa clicar, ele adiciona os dados na div:

```
$(".adicionar").click(function(){
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'resultado.php',
success: function(data) {
$(".tabela").append(data);
}
});
});
```

1) **.adicionar** é a classe que você deve adicionar em um botão no seu HTML.

2) **resultado.php** é o arquivo que faz a consulta SQL e retorna os dados. Pode utilizar **echo**.

3) **.tabela** é a classe que você deve adicionar na div que exibirá a tabela.

Comment: Então, eu não preciso realizar a consulta novamente, pois eu ja busco os produtos e armazeno em atributos dentro de um option. Nessa função `resultado.php` eu teria que salvar em um array e adiciona-lo a tabela?

Answer (score 1):

Tente usando Ajax e COOKIES, você cria um arquivo PHP que vai adicionando os pedidos à lista (que seria o cookie) e coloca uma função javascript que chama esse arquivo via ajax no botão **"OK"**, pega a resposta do arquivo em XML e adiciona na página com JS.

Exemplo de como utilizei em um projeto:

**PHP:**

```
<?php // Página que adiciona os produtos no carrinho    
    $id = $_GET['id'];  // ID do produto selecionado

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['carrinho'])) { // Verifica se o carrinho está vazio
        $carrinho = [0 => $id]; // A 1ª posição do array $carrinho (criado aqui) recebe o id do produto
        setcookie('carrinho', serialize($carrinho), time()+60*60*24*14, '/'); // Serializa o array no COOKIE carrinho
    } else {
        $carrinho = unserialize($_COOKIE['carrinho']); // Se não estiver vazio, cria um array com todos os produtos do carrinho
        $colocar = false; // Booleano que uso pra não repitir o mesmo produto

        // Checo se o produto selecionado já está no carrinho
        for ($i=0; $i < count($carrinho); $i++) { 
            if (!(in_array($id, $carrinho))) {
                $colocar = true;
            }
        }

        // Só adiciono ao carrinho se não tiver o produto nele ainda
        if ($colocar == true) {
            $carrinho[] = $id;
        }

        // Serializo o array dentro do COOKIE carrinho
        setcookie('carrinho', serialize($carrinho), time()+60*60*24*14, '/');
    }

    // Mando o número de produtos no carrinho como resposta, apenas para atualizar a tela do usuário
    echo count($carrinho);
?>
```

**JS:**

```js
// Função que adiciona o produto no carrinho
function adicionarCarrinho(id) { 
 id = $(id).val(); // Pego o ID do produto como parâmetro (vc pode colocar o id no value do botão)
 
 AjaxRequest();

 if (!Ajax) {
  alert("Erro na chamada Ajax");
 } else {
  Ajax.onreadystatechange = respostaCarrinho;
  Ajax.open('GET', '_assets/ajax/adicionarCarrinho.php?id='+id); // Mando o ID para a página PHP por meio do Ajax
  Ajax.send(null);
  Ajax.close;
 }
}

// Função de resposta
function respostaCarrinho() {
 if (Ajax.readyState == 4) {
  if (Ajax.status == 200) {
   $("#itens").text(Ajax.responseText); // Mudo o valor escrito no carrinho
   if (Ajax.responseText == '0') {
    alert('Você não tem produtos no carrinho');
    window.location.href='index.php'
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Então, desculpa, uma coisa que não comentei, os produtos já estão cadastrados no banco, chamar os produtos do banco não seria um problema, mas sim adicionar a lista usando eles sem recarregar a página

Comment: Então, não sei realmente se esse é o melhor modo de o fazer, mas num antigo projeto usei ajax pra chamar uma página que setava um cookie contendo um array dos produtos selecionados pelo usuário.

Comment: Você consegue me mostrar um exemplo, eu ainda to em duvida, sobre como funciona, eu to tentando com session, mas não esta funcionando

Comment: Deixei como exemplo o código que utilizei em um trabalho do curso, lembrando que não tenho total certeza de q esse seria o melhor método, iniciei a pouco tempo com Ajax, mas pra mim funcionou como esperado.